# How to setup Vue.JS to have JSX and TypeScript working together

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, jsx

JSX works perfectly in my Vue.JS project ... Unless I use typescript.

I create a Vue.JS project **without typescript**

```
vue create test
cd test
npm run serve
```

I replace `HelloWorld.vue` by

```
<script>
import Vue from 'vue';

export default Vue.extend({
  name: 'HelloWorld',
  render(){return (<p>JSX !</p>)},
});
</script>
```

And it's working perfectly

I make an other project, but **with typescript**, replace again `HelloWorld.vue`, I get an error

```
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (4:35)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
| export default Vue.extend({
|     name: 'HelloWorld',
>     render: function (h) { return (<p>JSX !</p>); }
| });
|
```

I've tried every thin clue I've found on internet: I've tried writting `HelloWorld.tsx` instead, configuring babel or tsconfig, I've tried creating `jsx.d.ts`, installing more packages, ... Everytime I get exactly this error.

Could anybody give me the magic recipe for having a Vue.JS project with both JSX and typescript ?